# What is better? Lots of small TCP packets, or one long one?

Tags: networking

I am sending quite a bit of data to and from a server, for a game I'm making.

I currently send location data like this:

```
sendToClient((("UID:" + cl.uid +";x:" + cl.x)));
sendToClient((("UID:" + cl.uid +";y:" + cl.y)));
sendToClient((("UID:" + cl.uid +";z:" + cl.z)));
```

Obviously it is sending the respective X, Y, and Z values.

Would it be more efficient to send data like this?

```
sendToClient((("UID:" + cl.uid +"|" + cl.x + "|" + cl.y + "|" + cl.z)));
```

Comment: Packet loss is usually under 5%, in my limited experience.

Comment: Does sendToClient actually send a packet? If so, how did you make it do that?

Comment: @immibis It's a method in my server code.

Comment: @mucaho I've never measured it myself or anything, but I'm surprised TCP is that rough around the edges.  I would've hoped for something more like 0.5% or less.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I must agree with you. I personally feel that a 5% loss would be unacceptable. If you think about something like me sending, say, a new ship spawned in the game, even a 1% chance of that packet not being received would be disastrous, because I would get invisible ships.

Comment: don't freak out guys, I meant the 5% as an upper bound :) in reality it's much better, as noted by other comments.

Comment: @mucaho Is there any way I can KNOW that a packet has been lost, and so can re-send or compensate for it?

Comment: @joehot200 you shouldn't be able to extract information for lost packets out of any TCP implementation (transport layer hides transport implementation details from application layer), so no. why would you want to resend it, since TCP guarantees it will resend it for you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A TCP segment has quite a lot of overhead. When you send a 10 byte message with one TCP packet you actually send:

- 16 bytes of IPv4 header (will increase to 40 byte when IPv6 becomes common)
- 16 bytes of TCP header
- 10 bytes of payload
- additional overhead for the data-link and physical layer protocols used

resulting in 42 bytes of traffic for transporting 10 byte of data. So you only make use of less than 25% of your available bandwidth. And that does not yet account for the overhead which the lower-level protocols like Ethernet or PPPoE consume (but these are hard to estimate because there are so many alternatives).

Also, many small packets put more strain on routers, firewalls, switches and other network infrastructure equipment, so when you, your service provider and your users don't invest in high-quality hardware, this might turn into another bottleneck.

For that reason you should try to send all data you have available at once in one TCP segment.

**Regarding handling packet loss**: When you use TCP you don't need to worry about that. The protocol itself ensures that any lost packets are resent and packets are processed in order, so you can assume that all packets you send will arrive at the other side, and they will arrive in the order you send them. The price for this is that when there is packet loss, your player will experience considerable lag, because one dropped packet will halt the whole data-stream until it was re-requested and received.

When this is a problem, you can always use UDP. But then you need to find your own solution for lost and out-of-order messages (it at least guarantees that the messages which *do* arrive, arrive complete and undamaged).

Comment: Does the overhead from the way TCP recovers packet loss vary worth anything depending on the packets' sizes?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Only in so far as there is a larger packet which needs to be resent.

Comment: That's mainly what I'm wondering about.  Like if it causes much of a bottleneck or anything because of it.

Comment: For 10baseT, I think one should add an extra 64 bytes to the cost function; for 100baseT, the cost is probably higher (since it's based on the propagation time over a maximum-length network segment).

Comment: I would note that the OS will almost certainly apply Nagles Algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm to outgoing data, this means that it does not matter if in the app you do separate writes or combine them, it will combine them before actually passing them out via TCP.

Comment: @Vality Most socket APIs I've used allow to activate or deactivate nagle for each socket. For most games I would recommend to deactivate it, because low latency is usually more important than conserving bandwidth.

Comment: That is forgeting the overhead bellow IP. For a xDSL connection using PPPoEoA, you will have: 2 bytes for the PPP header, 6 for the PPPoE header, 14 bytes for the Ethernet header, 4 bytes for the Ethernet trailer, 3--8 bytes for LLC+NLPID/SNAP (if LLC encapsulation is used) and for each ATM cell (at least one) 8 bytes for the AAL5 header and 5 bytes for the ATM header. An if your  using IPv6, the IP header is 40 bytes

Comment: @ysdx updated the answer

Comment: Nagle's algorithm is one, but not the only reason data may be buffered on the sending side. There is [no way](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml) to reliably force data sends. Also, buffering/fragmentation may occur anywhere after data is sent, either at NATs, routers, proxies, or even the receiving side. TCP does not make any guarantees regarding the size and timing at which you receive data, only that it will arrive in order and reliably. If you need size guarantees, use UDP. The fact that TCP *seems* easier to understand doesn't make it the best tool for all problems!

Answer (score 10):

One large one (within reason) is better.

As you said, packet loss is the main reason.  Packets are generally sent in frames of a fixed size, so it is better to take up one frame with a big message than 10 frames with 10 small ones.

However with standard TCP, this isn't really an issue, unless you disable it.  (It is called [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), and for games you should disable it.)  TCP will wait for a fixed timeout or until the package is "full".  Where "full" is would be some slightly magic number, determined in part by the frame size.

Comment: I've heard of Nagle's algorithm, but is it really a good idea to disable it? I just came right from a StackOverflow answer where someone said that it is more efficient (and for obvious reasons I want efficiency).

Comment: @joehot200 The only correct answer to that is "it depends". It is more efficient for sending lots of data, yes, but not for real-time streaming that games tend to need.

Comment: @joehot200: Nagle's algorithm interacts poorly with a delayed-acknowledgment algorithm which certain TCP implementations sometimes use.  Some TCP implementations will delay sending an ACK after they get some data if they expect more data to follow soon after (since acknowledging the later packet would implicitly acknowledge the earlier one as well).  Nagle's algorithm says that a unit shouldn't send a partial packet if it has sent some data but not heard an acknowledgment.  Sometimes the two approaches interact badly, with each parties waiting for the other to do something, until...

Comment: ...a "sanity timer" kicks in and resolves the situation (on the order of a second).

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling Nagle's algorithm will do nothing to prevent buffering on the other host side. Disabling Nagle's algorithm does not ensure you get one `recv()` call for each `send()` call, which is what most people are looking for. Using a protocol that guarantees this, like UDP does though.

"When all you have is TCP, everything looks like a stream"

Comment: @PandaPajama, Since this is his game, He's writing the server as well and of course he'll disable buffering on the server side to reduce latency.

Comment: @Pacerier: And how do you do that? Also keep in mind that when it comes to TCP, NAT's, proxies and even routers may split/join TCP segments while in transit. TCP is meant to be a *stream* protocol, and treating it as a *message* protocol will inevitably lead to abstraction leaks.

Answer (score 6):

All the previous answers are incorrect. In practice, it doesn't matter whether you issue one long `send()` call or several small `send()` calls.

As Phillip states, a TCP segment has some overhead, but as an application programmer, you have no control over how segments are generated. In simple terms:

> One `send()` call does not necessarily translate to one TCP segment.

The OS is [completely free](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml) to buffer all of your data and send it in one segment, or take the long one and break it into several small segments.

This has several implications, but the most important one is that:

> One `send()` call, or one TCP segment does not necessarily translate to one successful `recv()` call on the other end

The reasoning behind this is that TCP is a **stream** protocol. TCP treats your data as a long stream of bytes, and has absolutely no concept of "packets". With `send()` you add bytes to that stream, and with `recv()` you get bytes off the other side. TCP will aggressively buffer and split your data wherever it sees fit to make sure your data gets to the other side as fast as possible.

If you want to send and receive "packets" with TCP, you have to implement packet start markers, length markers and so on. How about using a message oriented protocol like UDP instead? UDP guarantees one `send()` call translates to one sent datagram and to one `recv()` call!

> *When all you have is TCP, everything looks like a stream*

Comment: Prefixing each message with a message length is not so tricky.

Comment: You have one switch to flip when it comes to packet aggregation, whether Nagle's Algorithm is in effect or not. It's not uncommon that it's off in game networking to ensure prompt delivery of underfilled packets.

Comment: This is completely OS or even library specific. Also you DO have a lot of control - if you want. It is true you do not have total control, TCP is always allowed to combine two messages, or split one if it doesn't fit the MTU, but you can still hint it in the right direction. Setting various config settings, manual sending messages 1 second apart or buffering data and send it in one shot.

Comment: @ysdx: no, not on the sending side, but yes on the receiving side. Since you have no guarantees on where exactly you will get data on `recv()`, you need to make your own buffering to compensate for that. I would rank it in the same difficulty as implementing reliability over UDP.

Comment: @Pagnda Pajama: A naive implementation of the receiving side is: `while(1) { uint16_t size; read(sock, &size, sizeof(size)); size = ntoh(size); char message[size]; read(sock, buffer, size); handleMessage(message); }` (omitting error handling and partial reads for brevity but it does not change much). Doing this is a `select` does not add much more complexity and if you are using TCP you probably need to buffer the partial messages anyway. Implementing robust reliability over UDP is much more complicated than that.

Comment: @ysdx: Have you ever implemented reliability over UDP?

Comment: @ysdx: Whatever. My point is not about the complexity of writing a message abstraction over TCP, but that TCP is a stream oriented protocol, which creates many hurdles when you try to use it for messages. How about using a message oriented protocol like UDP? That's what it's there for...

Comment: I don't think that the main selling point for UDP is its datagram/message orientation. (Nearly) all protocols over TCP are message/packet oriented (HTTP, TLS, SMTP, DNS, OpenVPN, WebSocket, POP, IMAP, SSH, etc) and use some form of framing over the TCP stream. UDP is interesting when you do not want reliability or/and in-order messages delivery; or if you do not want flow control; or if you have many  shortlived interactions with many peers; or for broadcast/multicast. For a real-time game, UDP is a good choice but I don't think it's because of its message orientation.

Comment: That beeing said, I agree with your answer. The OP just needs to be aware that he won't get builtin reliability and message ordering and will probably need to build this on top of UDP if it is needed. (Maybe using something like [Enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) might be a good idea).

Comment: @ysdx: No. TCP vs UDP is not about reliable vs. unreliable, even though that's what most people would like to believe. TCP vs UDP is about stream vs message. HTTP, TLS, SMTP, (DNS is UDP based) and so on are not message based. For example, HTTP is about sending lots of data (files), regardless of the timing at which each specific chunk arrives, that's a stream abstraction using a stream protocol. Reliability is an effect of creating a stream protocol; message protocols don't require reliability, and as such they don't include it by default, but you can do it yourself, and it's not hard.

Comment: @ysdx once I started using http://zeromq.org/ I never looked back

Comment: For reference, DNS is usually used over UDP but [DNS is used over TCP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-4.2.2) as well with a length prefix for message framing.

Answer (score 3):

Many small packages is fine. In fact, if you are worried about TCP overhead, just insert a `bufferstream` that collect up to 1500 chars (or whatever your TCP MTUs is, best to request it dynamically), and deal with the problem in one place. Doing so spares you the overhead of ~40 bytes for every extra package you would otherwise have created.

That said, it's still better to send less data, and building larger objects help there. Ofcourse it's smaller to send `"UID:10|1|2|3` than to send `UID:10;x:1UID:10;y:2UID:10;z:3`. In fact, also at this point you should not be reinventing the wheel, use a library like **protobuf** that can decrease data like that to a 10 byte string or less.

Only thing you should not forget is to insert a `Flush` commands on your stream at relevant locations, because as soon as you stop adding data to your stream, it might wait infinite before it send anything. Really problematic when your client is waiting for that data, and your sever wont send anything new until the client send the next command.

Package loss is something you can affect here, marginally. Every byte you send can potentially be corrupted, and TCP will automatically request a retransmission. Smaller packages means a lower chance for every single package to be corrupted, but because they add up on the overhead, you send even more bytes, increasing the odds of a lost package even more. When a package is lost, TCP will buffer all succeeding data until the missing package is resend and received. This result in a large delay (ping). While the total loss in bandwidth because of package loss might be negligible, the higher ping would be undesirable for games.

**Bottom line:** Send as little data as possible, send large packages, and do not write your own low level methods to do so, but rely on well known libraries and methods like `bufferstream` and protobuf to handle the heavy lifting.

Comment: Actually for simple things like this its easy to roll your own. Much easier than going through a 50 page documentation to use another person's library, and then after that you've still got to deal with their bugs and gotchas.

Comment: True, writing your own `bufferstream` is trivial, that's why I called it a method. You still want to handle it in one place, and not integrate your buffer logic with your message code. As for Object Serialization, I highly doubt you get something better than the thousands of man-hours others put in there, even if you DO try, I strongly suggest you benchmark your solution against known implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Although being a neophyte to network programming myself, I would like to share my limited experience by adding a few points:

- TCP does imply an overhead - you must measure the relevant statistics
- UDP is the *de facto* solution for networked gaming scenarios, but all implementations that rely on it have an extra, CPU-side algorithm to account for packets being lost or being sent out of order

Concerning measurements, the metrics that should be considered are:

- **mean** and **instant throughput**
- **mean**, **maximum** and **minimum end-to-end delay**
  For such metrics, existing tools can provide a fast solution. For example: iperf (https://iperf.fr/), D-ITG(http://traffic.comics.unina.it/software/ITG/). A dated but still useful document on tuning TCP can be found at http://dst.lbl.gov/publications/usenix-login.pdf .

As mentioned, if you find out that you're not limited in a sense and could use UDP, go for that. There are some UDP-based implementations out there, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel or work against years of experience and proven experience. Such implementations worth mentioning are:

- reliable UDP http://sourceforge.net/projects/rudp/
- ENET http://enet.bespin.org/ (which could even replace TCP message handling if found to perform better)
- UDT (UDP-based Data Transfer protocol http://udt.sourceforge.net/) which seems to have become the norm in HP computing scenarios

Conclusion: since a UDP implementation could outperform (by a factor of 3x) a TCP one, it makes sense to consider it, once you've identified your scenario to be UDP friendly. Be warned! Implementing the full TCP stack on top of UDP is always a bad idea.

Comment: I was using UDP. I only just switched to TCP. UDP's packet loss was simply unacceptable for crucial data that the client needed. I may send movement data via UDP.

Comment: So, the best things that you can do are: indeed, use TCP just for crucial operations OR use an UDP based software protocol implementation (with Enet being simple and UDT being well tested). But first, measure the loss and decide whether UDT would bring you an edge.